How do I get the request host in .NET 8?
In .NET 4.5.2, this code worked in _layout.cshtml:
@{
    string s = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}

But in the same place in a .NET 8 project, the code causes an error:

The name 'request' does not exist in the current context

What should I use instead?

What kind of .NET 8 project?

Check out this answer for .NET Core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375481/1807452

You can try using RazorPage.Context:
@{
    string s = Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
}

Or RazorPageBase.ViewContext:
@{
    string s = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
}

UPD
ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Host was used.

string MyHost = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString(); This is the correct answer.

Thank you for providing the suggestion "ViewContext." However, "GetDisplayURL()" did not work. What worked is posted in my comment just above.
