# How to display the absolute url in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

How would I be able to get the absolute URL to display on a view?

I currently have this in my code:

```
<link href="~/css/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

..which displays like this:

```
<link href="/css/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What I am looking for is the following:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/css/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I know you could do it with the older `ASP.NET MVC 5`, but is this possible with the core versions?

Is it worthwhile having an absolute URL, or will a relative URL be sufficient?

Comment: I don't really see the need of a full URL in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You should construct the URL yourself.  take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609162/2669438), but I don't think an absolute url is required in your case.

Here is a summary of what you will find in that answer:

```
public static string AbsoluteContent(this IUrlHelper url, string contentPath)
{
    HttpRequest request = url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
    return new Uri(new Uri(request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host.Value), url.Content(contentPath)).ToString();
}
```

with that helper method, you will write this in your view to get the absolute URL to `site.css` located under `wwwroot`:

```
@Url.AbsoluteContent("~/site.css")
```