# Why @Url.Content() does not working for me (.NET 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to get the absolute path of a static file using @Url.Content on a razor view to use it as a value of content attr of a meta tag but It's seems not working for me I didn't know what is the problem.

```
@{
var pageThumbnail = Url.Content("~/assets/121545/mid.jpg");
}

@section Meta {
<meta property="og:image" content="@pageThumbnail" />
}
```

- Result :
  `<meta property="og:image" content="/assets/121545/mid.jpg" />`
- I expected this result instead:
  `<meta property="og:image" content="https://localhost:5001/assets/121545/mid.jpg" />`

Comment: What you are asking for is not supported yet, see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14192. You can follow the information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755827/getting-absolute-urls-using-asp-net-core if you want to use absolute URLs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting absolute URLs using ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755827/getting-absolute-urls-using-asp-net-core)

Comment: There's an overload `Url.Content("...", Request.Scheme, Request.Host)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `Context.Request.Host` to `pageThumbnail`:

```
@{
var pageThumbnail = Context.Request.Host + Url.Content("~/assets/121545/mid.jpg");
}

@section Meta {
<meta property="og:image" content="@pageThumbnail" />
}
```